# Template deduction, is this conforming?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

It seems like this code is not correct as I get compiler errors for it. I'm trying to understand why:

```
template <class ... Ts>
struct type_list{};

template <class ... Ts, class T_, class ... Ts_>
auto foo(type_list<Ts...>, Ts&&..., T_&&t, Ts_&&...) {
    return sizeof(T_);
}

int main() {
  std::cerr << foo(type_list<int>{}, 5, 5.0, 3);
  return 0;
}
```

clang produces the follow error:

```
example.cpp:16:16: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
  std::cerr << foo(type_list<int>{}, 5, 5.0, 3);
               ^~~
example.cpp:11:6: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'Ts'
      (<int> vs. <>)
auto foo(type_list<Ts...>, Ts&&..., T_&&t, Ts_&&...) {
```

It seems to me that in my call `Ts` should be deduced to `int` (since that's the only way to make the first argument work out), and then everything else will be forced as a result. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: How should the compiler decide which `Ts` to deduce?

Comment: @Fureeish [Wrong](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81e1375b29312960). @NirFriedman Any reason you want to use a `type_list` function argument instead of template arguments directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clang deduces `Ts` from two conflicting sources: `type_list<Ts...>` and `Ts&&...`. Because you call `foo` with `type_list<int>{}`, `Ts` is first deduced as `{int}`. However, because the last argument `Ts_&&...` has the type of a parameter pack, it catches all that it can; in this case, the last two arguments (while `T_&&t` is passed the `5`), which deduces `Ts_` as `{double, int}` (and `T_` as `int`). This leaves `Ts` with no argument, so it's deduced as `{}`.

Hence Clang's error message: `Ts` is deduced both as `{}` and `{int}` (the `(<int> vs. <>)` in the error message).

Note that GCC does things differently:

> error: too few arguments to function 'auto foo(type_list, Ts&& ..., T_&&, Ts_&& ...) [with Ts = {int}; T_ = int; Ts_ = {double, int}]'

It tries to keep `Ts` deduced as `{int}` but still deduces `Ts_` as `{double, int}`, and so there is no way to give the correct number of arguments.

To explain a bit further, consider the following:

```
template <class ... Ts>
struct type_list{};

template <class ... Ts>
auto foo(type_list<Ts...>, Ts...) {
    return sizeof...(Ts);
}

int main() {
  std::cerr << foo(type_list<int>{}, 5, 5.0, 3);
}
```

Clang correctly calls this out because the two deductions are conflicting:

> note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'Ts' (`<int>` vs. `<int, double, int>`)

Trouble is, you can't catch 2 of the arguments with another parameter pack, because it will either catch everything if placed after (which is your case), or nothing if placed before:

```
template <class ... Ts>
struct type_list{};

template <class... Ts, class... Ts_>
auto foo(type_list<Ts...>, Ts_..., Ts...) {
    return sizeof...(Ts);
}

int main() {
  std::cerr << foo(type_list<int>{}, 5, 5.0, 3);
}
```

Here, Clang produces the same error message because `Ts` is still deduced as both `{int}` from the `type_list`, and `{int, double, int}` by catching all the remaining arguments.

I think your only choices are to somehow deal with tuples or be more explicit with the call: `foo<int>(type_list<int>{}, 5, 5.0, 3)` (and you can probably remove the `type_list` in this case). That way, `Ts` isn't deduced anymore: you explicitly make it `{int}`.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't try every possibility and find the only one that is legal.  It follows very specific rules, and if those rules don't work, it generates an error.

In general, a deduced `...` pack must be last if it is deduced.  Attempts to work around it will fail.

Here is a solution that avoids your problem:

```
template <class ... Ts, class...Us>
auto foo(type_list<Ts...>, Us&&...us) {
    return [](Ts&&...ts, auto&& t, auto&&...) {
        return sizeof(t);
    }(std::forward<Us>(us)...);
}

int main() {
  std::cerr << foo(type_list<int>{}, 5, 5.0, 3);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the alternate solution!